# CSS margin too long

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

We have a button in our app that we want to put a header next to, but can't because the margins to the right of the button seem to extend all the way to the edge of the screen. This is occurring even though the button has its margin-right property set to 0. Any suggestions as to how we can get a header to the right of the button?

[image: This is a cropped view of Chrome developer tools]

Comment: "Any suggestions" questions are off-topic. You're required to provide enough information that debugging is possible. In this case, HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you post a snippet that demonstrates the issue? Oh well, let's cut to the chase. What is the value if the button's `display` property?

Comment: Display that button inline. Looking at the way that element's box model properties are highlighted there looks like you have a `block` element. Paste this in your url bar, then inspect the element, you'll see the same thing: `data:text/html,<button style="display: block;">button</button>`

Answer (score 4):

Give your button `display: inline-block;`.

**OR**

Remove your `btn-block` class.

Comment: Buttons are display:inline-block by default, so unless you are absolutely sure that's the problem, this is supposed to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Based on what he posted it looks like it's display: block. I could be wrong, but we won't know until the OP provides more info.

Comment: Yes, and you shouldn't answer prematurely. Guesswork is not what answers are for.

Comment: @MrLister I think he's actually right. note the "btn-block" class. More context would be helpful here, though, Hunter.

Comment: Well, the button has a class named btn-block and from what I can see it does look like a block-level element.

Comment: The correct answer though could be: remove btn-block class from the button.

Comment: I agree that this is likely the issue.  That's the same naming convention twitter bootstrap has for its buttons.  I'd be willing to bet OP is using that framework and that `btn-block` (which does add `display:block` to buttons in twitter bootstrap) is the problem.

Comment: Am I the only one who isn't amused by Hunter editing the OP's question to make it fit this answer? Oh well.

Comment: @MrLister, this is obviously bootstrap. I'm not changing anything to "fit my answer". All I added was the bootstrap tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap? Remove `btn-block` wrap the button in `<div class="col-md-2"></div>` & then have the header in another `<div class="col-md-10"></div>` otherwise you may need to provide more info.